# Android progressbar setprogress() function doesn’t work

Tags: android

I would setting progress of the progressbar in Android. But setprogress function doesn't work.

Codes XML:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hamlebar"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbarr"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/oyunhamletv"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/bartext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hamle"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hamlebar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/hamlebar"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hamlebar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hamlebar"

/>
```

Progress drawable codes (progressbarr.xml) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#234"
                    android:centerColor="#234"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a24"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#144281"
                    android:centerColor="#0b1f3c"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#f6101d"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Set progress codes (Java codes) :

```
hamlebar.setMax(oyunhamle);
oyunhamle = oyunhamle - 1;
hamlebar.setProgress(0);
hamlebar.setProgress(oyunhamle);
```

Note : I don’t had a good English. I hope you can understand. Pardon me.

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code its working fine at my end - 
I think you might have initialize `oyunhamle = 0;`(WRONG)

you just need to initialize - `oyunhamle = 100;` and then set max value of `progressbar` like - `hamlebar.setMax(oyunhamle);`

what you are doing wrong is you are substracting only 1 from the max value 100 so its not clearly visible `oyunhamle = oyunhamle - 1;`(WRONG)

try `oyunhamle = oyunhamle - 50;` and then set `hamlebar.setProgress(oyunhamle);`

it should work;

Comment: But I set max 5. And şet progress 4. Oyunhamle  is 5. Not 100.

Comment: if you initialize - oyunhamle = 5; and setMax(5) and then progress to 4 it should work I have checked this condition too... may be your background color  with progress bar creating issue please check that too.

Comment: I need change background color and progress bar color?

Comment: yeh may be as I can see you you decreased progress color is getting mixed up with the background while color, may be you can either add border to progressbar or change decrease progress color .

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I can’t do now. I will do in the evening.

Comment: I changed the colors but the result doesn’t changed.